How does light intencity work on a sphere?
I was working on a problem where earth was a blackbody and the sun was shining 1400W/m^2 on the earth. The details of the problem don’t matter but i made the mistake of calculating the power for the surface area of a halfsphere not the cross-section of the sphere.
I understand intuitively why the light only works on a cross-section of a sphere, as the light falls on a bigger angle the closer to the edge you are, but how exactly does this work? I would just really appreciate if anyone knew some good reading material on this as i am so intrigued, what if the sun was the size of the earth, how does the scattering affect how much surface area we need to account for? I have so many questions and i have found it so hard to find any answers. I would apprechiate anything!

Just an intuitive guess from me: in every point on the surface of the earth, you can decompose the incoming light rays into a component perpendicular and a component parallel to the surface. Only the component perpendicular to the surface will deposit energy as the parallel component never actually hits the surface. If you sum all the perpendicular components over the half sphere, this should be equivalent to the sum of the normals on the cross section of the earth. Hence, the weighted number of rays penetrating the surface is equal to the number of normals on the cross-section.

I guess you are calculating the mean temperature of the Earth. When the Sun's rays hit the Earth, you can either use the cross-sectional area $\pi r^2$ perpendicular to the Sun's rays, or you can integrate every surface area element over the hemisphere facing the Sun; you should prove to yourself that the result is the same. When the Earth is radiating to space, you will need to take the entire Earth's surface area $4\pi r^2$. Only then will you get an acceptable mean temperature of the Earth.
